# Installing PHP on IIS 6 (Win2003)

Tags: php

I have been trying to install PHP 5.3.6 on a clean install of Win2003, no dot net or anything else much installed.  Unfortunately I have tried 'thread safe', 'non thread safe', installer file, zip file etc. but whatever I try PHP just doesn't seem to work.  I have also installed Microsoft C++ 2008 redistributable as suggested on PHP site but still nothing.

Any suggestions on how I should actually be installing this properly.  There seems to be vague and at times conflicting instructions on the PHPweb site.

Comment: Can you point to any specific issues / errors / etc that you're getting? Unfortunately there are a lot of reasons why your install might not be working and simply saying "it's not working" is not sufficient to diagnose your particular problem.

Comment: You'll have to give some more information than "doesn't work". Where are you stuck, what error messages you get...

Comment: Thats just the problem no error messages simply that .php files don't get interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And further investigation reveals I was wrong - it is now installed and working.

Download and install FastCGI from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=227219AA-6AEC-4B80-A9FA-76F811EE9E84&amp%3Bdisplaylang=en
This is a simple .msi install, no dot net required.

Restart IIS

Then download the NON Thread Safe PHP and install to IIS FastCGI Server option.

Now all working.

Comment: It also appears that Microsoft C++ 2008 redistributable is not required as the PHP website suggests it is.

Comment: Good information. I'll keep this in mind if we ever need to upgrade. Mark it as the answer so others can learn from what you found out!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have told IIS how to handle PHP files.
In IIS Manager, expand the tree and find web service extensions, then make sure you have a spot for PHP, pointing to the php dll.

[image: service extensions]

then make sure that your MIME types are set up correctly. Right click your website under Web Sites, view properties, then the HTTP Headers Tab. Click the MIME Types button, and make sure you have an entry for PHP.

[image: mime types]

This is how we got it set up in IIS Manager. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks AndyD, just tried your suggestions.  Only problem is that my c:\Program files\PHP does not have a PHP5isapi.dll, but it does have PHP5nsapi.dll which I have used instead.  This time round I have installed the threadsafe version of 5.3.6.  Same problem my Test2.php file simply returns the page cannot be found, all other .htm files and even .shtm files in the same directory work fine.

Comment: Have downloaded .zip for both thread safe and non thread safe but neither contain a PHP5isapi.dll.  Could the lack of this file be causing my problem?

Comment: Hmm, the version of PHP we have is 5.2.5.5. You have some good information on the FastCGI thing. In case we ever need to upgrade. I never got a page cannot be found either... when I didn't have it set up right it would return the page as a download instead of rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

Further investigation suggests that PHP 5.3.x will only work with IIS using FastCGI; isapi is no longer supported hence the reason that PHP5isapi.dll is missing.  Unfortunately FastCGI cannot be installed on IIS without first installing Microsoft Web Platform Installer which requires dot net to be installed first.

This is crazy, PHP are effectively insisting that dot net is a pre-requisite for PHP - madness!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I installed PHP 5.3 on IIS 6 (running on Windows 2003 server):
http://www.howtoadvice.com/PHPIIS

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://blogs.iis.net/mailant/archive/2009/04/01/php-installed-using-the-microsoft-web-platform-installer-v2-beta.aspx) is a little old and outdated but you should be able to use [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to install PHP on IIS6 for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I am not mistaken, that required dot net 2 installed before it will run.  As I am not intending to be running any .net on this server I was hoping to avoid the bloated overhead of having to install dot net.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In that case, this won't be of much use to you.